# Java webservice client with ADFS SAML authentication

Tags: java, web-services, soap, saml, adfs

We are trying to connect to **webservice** (from **Java**) that has **ADFS SAML** authentication.

All the examples I have seen, use **Basic Authentication over HTTPS**. (I am just using HttpsURLConnection to make a request for now, not using anything like Axis or JAX-WS)

I am not sure how to approach **ADFS SAML** authentication. Here's what I understand so far (don't know much about **SAML**):

1. I make one request, pass *username/password* and get the
   **authentication token** back
2. Save the **authentication token**
3. Pass the token as some **SOAP** attribute in my calls where I invoke an
   actual operation on the **webservice**
4. No idea under which attribute would I put this **authentication token** though

Is my above approach correct? If so, is there some library that I can use that does all this?

If not how can I go about doing this manually?

Please let me know if there are other or better ways of going about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build native app then can use below code. i has tried to use power bi rest apis. once you gets token you can use that in api calls.

```
public class PublicClient {

    private final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
    private final static String CLIENT_ID = "XXXX-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxX";
    private final static String RESOURCE = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.print("Enter username: ");
            String username = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter password: ");
            String password = br.readLine();
            AuthenticationResult result = getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
                    username, password);
            System.out.println("Access Token - " + result.getAccessToken());
            System.out.println("Refresh Token - " + result.getRefreshToken());
            System.out.println("ID Token Expires on - " + result.getExpiresOn());
        }
    }

    private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
            String username, String password) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                    RESOURCE, CLIENT_ID, username, password, null);
            result = future.get();
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }

        if (result == null) {
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException(
                    "authentication result was null");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is CLIENT_ID supposed to have? Also which libraries do I need for AuthenticationResult and AuthenticationContext?

Comment: @nullpointer The source code provided by Rahul Patel implements OpenID Connect/OAuth 2.0 protocol instead of SAML protocol. CLIENT_ID, Access Token, Refresh Token, and are ID Token OpenID Connect/OAuth 2.0 parameters.

Comment: @nullpointer `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.aad</groupId>
    <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
</dependency>  `      based on your app type (Native/ web app) you need to register application on azure portal, for that application you will be having CLIENT_ID. if you have web app, some other parameter also would be there. All things are well document on somewhere in Microsoft site.